# Schedule SSRS report when a row is inserted or updated in oracle table

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have an oracle table from which i generate report in SSRS. Is there a way to schedule report to run when an insert or update is done on that table?

Comment: How do you determine when an update is done?

Comment: Can i use an oracle insert, update, delete trigger and use it to fire report?

Comment: There is an updated date column in table which updates everytime an update is done.

Comment: I would suggest to you that you not run reports on table triggers, as your response is indicating. Why would you use ssrs when a table is updated?

Comment: Oh ok thanks, Because the end users want to know whenever that table data is changed a report be generated by querying on same table and be sent to them. The SSRS is the reporting system on the oracle table.

Comment: I assume you don't have a service agent that can run ssrs reports on a schedule. In that case I would look into the subscription service of ssrs and run timed reports...as opposed to some database trigger process:)

Comment: Thanks for info. I haven't looked into architecture yet and i'm developing oracle views and SSRS reports. Will check if subscription service allows to handle this type of situation.